# Is there a way to hide or replace the logo in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to hide or replace the "Azure DevOps" logo in the top left corner of Azure DevOps. Maybe with a company logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can go to UserVoice to request this feature if it's important to you.